# Two classes within the same package aren't working together

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, methods, each

I've created a package called `EstateAgent` and within it I have two
classes:
`Property` and `ArrayOfProperties`.

My `Property` class works perfectly, but my `ArrayOfProperties` has an error
line under the title and I can't use any of my get() methods from
`Property` in `ArrayOfProperties`

I've imported the package and other class at the beginning of `ArrayOfProperties` but it still won't work

```java
package EstateAgent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 * Created by 60005358 ON 10/03/2021
 * Program to define an ArrayOfProperties Class
 */
public class ArrayOfProperties {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //1. Defining a class with one attribute - a list of property objects
    private List<Property> properties;
    // class created to store a list of property objects

    //2. Defining a constructor that creates a new ArrayList of Property objects
    public void Properties() {
        properties = new ArrayList<Property>();
    }
    // Constructor created which creates an ArrayList for Property objects

    //3. Define methods
    // define a method called getCurrent to reference a property at a particular index position
    protected Property getCurrent(int position) {
        return properties.get(position);
    }

    // getCurrent method which references a property at a particular position
    // Return the number of Property objects created called getNoOfProperties
    protected int getNoOfProperties(int position) {
        return properties.size();
    }

    // getNoOfProperties which returns the number of Properties that have been created
    //Method to return the street of a Property at a particular index position called getStreet()
    protected String getStreet(int position) {
        return properties.get(position).getStreet();
    }

    // getStreet returns properties at a particular index position
    // Insert a new Property object called insert(). Confirmation of addition of new property should be output
    protected void insert(Property newProperty) {
        properties.add(newProperty);
        System.out.println(newProperty.getStreet() + "Added");
    }
    //Adds a new Property object to the ArrayList

    // Remove a property method. Confirmation of removal should be output to the console
    protected void removeProperties(int position) {
        properties.remove(position);
        System.out.println("Property removed");
    }
    // Removes a Property object from the ArrayList

    // Return the index position (or -1 if not found) of a property at a particular street called findPropertyByStreet()
    protected void findPropertyByStreet(String Street) {
        int index = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        int position = -1;

        if (properties.get(position).getStreet().equals(Street)) {
            found = true;
            position = index;
            index++;
            System.out.println(position);
        }//if
        while (found == false && index < properties.size()) {
            System.out.print("-1");
        }//while
    }//findPropertyByStreet
    // Returns the index position for a property at a particular street (or  -1 if not found) called findPropertyByStreet

    // Return the range of indices (or an empty list if not found) of any  properties in a particular town
    // (called findPropertyByTown(...) - the town should be passed as a  parameter.
    protected ArrayList<Integer> findPropertyByTown(String town) {
        int index = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 0; i <= getNoOfProperties(); i++) ;
        {
            if (town(i).equals(getTown())) ;
            {
                return town.getTown().equals(town);
                if (town.getTown().equals(town)) ;
                {

                }

            }


            //int ArrayList<Integer> result(int result) = 0;

            // ArrayList<Integer>result = ArrayList<Integer>result ++ index;
        }
        //System.out.println(ArrayList<Integer>result);

        //protected Property getCurrent(int position) { return
        properties.get(position);
    } //findPropertyByTown


    // Print address, property type, price, date registered and the vendor's  details of a property at a particular
    // index position (called displayAProperty(...)) - the index position  should be passed as a parameter
    public void displayAProperty(int position) {
        System.out.println("\nAddress: " + fullAddress);
        System.out.println("Property Type:         " + propertyType);
        System.out.println("Price:         £");
        System.out.println("%,10%", Price);
        System.out.println("Date Registered:      " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-  MM-yyyy").format(dateRegistered));
        System.out.println("Vendors Name:     " + nameOfVendor);
        System.out.println("Vendors Contact Number:     " + VendorContactNumber);
    }// displayAProperty returns the address
    // , property type, price, date registered, vendors name and number of a
    //property at a passed position


    // Print address, property type, price, date registered and the  vendor's details of all registered properties
    // called displayAllProperties()
    protected void displayAllProperties() {
        for (int position; position <= properties.size(); position++) ;
        System.out.println(displayProperty());
    } //displayAllProperties

}//class
```

I've 13 errors currently:

> ```
> 'getNoOfProperties(int)' in 'EstateAgent.ArrayOfProperties' cannot be applied to '()'
> Cannot resolve symbol 'i'
> Cannot resolve method 'getTown' in 'ArrayOfProperties'
> Cannot resolve method 'getTown' in 'String'
> Cannot resolve method 'getTown' in 'String'
> Cannot resolve symbol 'fullAddress'
> Cannot resolve symbol 'propertyType'
> Cannot resolve symbol 'Price'
> Cannot resolve symbol 'dateRegistered'
> Cannot resolve symbol 'nameOfVendor'
> Cannot resolve symbol 'VendorContactNumber'
> Variable 'position' might not have been initialized
> Cannot resolve method 'displayProperty' in 'ArrayOfProperties'
> ```

I know int ArrayList result(int result) = 0; code is wrong (still attempting it. It's really disaplayAProperty() and displayAllProperties please

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Describing your code rarely works well. Instead prepare a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [edit] your question to share that with us.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ash93 not in comments, please. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Also, when you edit your question please include the exact error you're getting as well.

Comment: While editing the code for ArrayOfProperties, I couldn't help but notice an extra } which might screw up the scope. Please check that. If you are using an IDE, use the IDE specific formatting options, if you are not using an IDE, please use one.

Comment: description and implementation of `getNoOfProperties` does not match; missing its argument in call later on; multiple semi-colons `;` after `if` or `for` (empty statement); statement after `return`... (partially) commented out code; `town.getTown()` does not make sense (`town` is a string)